# Calculating mean and standard deviation between separate groups in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data set:

```html
df1<-read.table(text=" people time range value1 value2 value3
1 21 2 2 4 4
1 21 12 3 5 1
1 41 2 1 5 4
12 41 12 3 5 2
12 33 12 1 5 5
11 33 2 5 2 2
11 41 2 1 2 5
",header=TRUE)
```

I want to calculate mean and sd for each group( people (1,12,11), time (21,41,33) range 2,12), Value 1 goes to people, value2 goes time and value3 goes to the range.

I want to get the following table:

```html
people value1M value1SD time value2M value2SD range value3M value3SD
1 2 1 21 4.5 0.707106781 2 1.258305739 1.5
12 2 1.414213562 41 4 1.732050808 12 2.081665999 2.081665999
11 3 2.828427125 33 3.5 2.121320344
```

I have used the following function, but they do not work for me

```html
df%>%
    group_by(people,time,range) %>%
summarise_at(vars(starts_with('value')), sd,mean)
```

Comment: You can wrap it in `list(sd, mean)`. Note that when you are grouping by the 3. columns, some of them have only one row and this means your sd will be NA

Comment: Please check `df1 %>% count(people, time, range)` only 1 row for each group

Comment: What I meant to say with `count` is the frequency of 1 as you are trying to do `sd` by group

Comment: Do you need corresponding group/mean/sd i.e. `map2(names(df1)[1:3], names(df1)[4:6], ~ df1 %>% select(.x, .y) %>% group_by_at(.x) %>% summarise_at(1, list(sd = sd, mean = mean)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to do corresponding group summmary, then use `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rowr)
map2(names(df1)[1:3], names(df1)[4:6], ~
       df1 %>% 
          dplyr::select(.x, .y) %>%
          group_by_at(.x) %>% 
          summarise_at(1, list(sd = sd, mean = mean))) %>% 
  reduce(cbind.fill, fill = NA)
# people       sd mean time      sd.1 mean.1 range       sd     mean
#1      1 1.000000    2   21 0.7071068    4.5     2 1.258306 3.750000
#2     11 2.828427    3   33 2.1213203    3.5    12 2.081666 2.666667
#3     12 1.414214    2   41 1.7320508    4.0    NA       NA       NA
```

---

Or instead of column names, we can subset the columns and use that in `map2`

```
map2(df1[1:3], df1[4:6], ~  
    tibble(grp = .x, value = .y) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarise(valueSD = sd(value), valueMean = mean(value))) %>% 
    reduce(cbind.fill, fill = NA)
```

---

Or using `lapply`

```
lapply(1:3, function(i) 
      df1[c(i, i + 3)] %>% 
         group_by_at(1) %>% 
         summarise_all(list(mean, sd))) %>% 
   reduce(cbind.fill, fill = NA)
```

Comment: @User20100 Updated with `lapply`